# How to get specific string value from a command line in gpg for secret key?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

When I do this command, I got the following Keygrip value but it has 2. How do I get the first Keygrip value (0FCB25C3D73CC979F7732F5690E958A580D873B9) that should be in the "sec" section ?

```
root $> gpg --with-keygrip --list-secret-keys  F9211C72F41103B4

sec   rsa2048 2020-08-19 [SC]
      BC777712D75642B7F3D50980F6031C73F46103B4
      Keygrip = 0FCB25C3D73CC979F7732F5690E958A580D873B9   //<-- how to get this one
uid           [ultimate] Kalib Zen (Backup Key) <key@staffm.com>
ssb   rsa2048 2020-08-19 [E]
      Keygrip = 75DECACEB6DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD28392832323232
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output of your gpg command to either of the grep /sed/awk commands shown below.

Employing `GNU grep` with the PCRE engine enabled(`-P`), select only the matching portion(`-o`), and get just the first match(`-m1`). The `\K` is used to keep away the non included portion of the line.

```
grep -Pom1 '^ *Keygrip += +\K.*'
```

`GNU sed` with Gnu-specific construct `T`
for the inverted test command

```
sed -Ene 's/^ *Keygrip += +//;T;p;q'

###Or Posixly, 
sed -e '/^ *Keygrip  *=  */!d;s///;q'
```

With `awk` you set the field separator to "one_or_more_spc=one_or_more_spc"
and print the 2nd field after ensuring the appropriate first field  and line has exactly two fields.

```
awk -F' += +' '
  /^ *Keygrip / && NF==2 {
    print $2;exit
  }'
```

Comment: I'm confused with the expression here. '^ *Keygrip += +\K.*' . Do you know where is the best resources to learn this. I'm trying to avoid askin too much regex question I want to learn my own but I dont understand much. Please guide me to the resources. I know programming language but when come to regex I'm weak.

Comment: A regex is a constraint on the string against which it is matched. Regex `^ Keygrip += +\K` => the line must begin with a space, followed by the string Keygrip, followed by atleast one space ( +), followed by (=), followed by atleast one space ( +), the final \K is to instruct the tool to not include this portion in the matched output. There are very many hood sites like rexegg.com which have good materials. Regardless, but the final understanding will happen when after acquiring the regex skills you come to this site and try to solve the queries raised w/o looking at the answers. HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much for useful information.